# When is a matrix similar to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have a matrix $A \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that it's characteristic polynomial is $p_{A}(t) = t^2$. Prove that $A$ is either similar to the zero matrix or similar to $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

So far what I have done. Let 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then since $Tr(A)=0$ and $det(A)=0$
$$a+d=0$$
$$ad-bc=0$$
So $A$ actually has the from 
$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\
c & -a \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Second the only matrix that is similar to the zero matrix would be the case when $A =0_2$ since if $AS = S0_2 = 0_2$ then A=0_2 as $S$ is invertible. 
So now it comes down to solving the system 
$$AS = S
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & -a\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
z & w \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
z & w \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which boils down to solving this set of equations:

$$ax +bz=0$$
$$cx -aw=0$$
$$ay+bw=x$$
$$cy-aw=z$$
$$xw -yz \neq 0$$

I have not been able to figure out a solution to this system. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\det A=0$, there is a non-null vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ such that $A.v=0$. Let $w=(w_1,w_2)$ be some vector of $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $v$ and $w$ are linearly indepndent. Let$$P=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&w_1\\v_2&w_2\end{bmatrix}.$$Then, since $A.v=0$, the left column of $P^{-1}AP$ only has $0$'s. In other words$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}0&\alpha\\0&\beta\end{bmatrix},$$for some numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But, since $A$ and $P^{-1}AP$ have the same trace, which is $0$, $\beta=0$. So,$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}0&\alpha\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$It is not hard to prove now that you can change $P$ a bit so that $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot I knew there had to be a better way to do it, other than solving that horrible system!